# Show Different type of Data in Same Visual In Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a scenario where I have a column in a table which is having multiple project list.
And each project is of different type.
And the types are for ex FP and T&M.
Now as we can see in First image , Charge Ratio is showing for FP type Projects and Second Image showing Bill Utilization for T&M Projects[image: Now as we can see in First image , Charge Ratio is showing for FP type Projects.]

.[image: and Second Image showing Bill Utilization for T&M Projects]

My Requirement is ,I want to show both The Charge Ratio and Bill Utilization in One Visual According to the Project Type.
I have a slicer which user can choose the projects.
If the choosen project is T&M type then it should show visual according to that type.
If it is FP then in that line chart only, i would like to show the visuals according to that type.

Note:- I don't want to use the slicer for TYPE selection

Please Give me suggestion.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you have some sample data, and perhaps some (hand-drawn) pictures of your desired end result? You can have 2 lines on the same line chart (i.e. on one visual). Are you saying that you only want one line to appear at a time though, depending on what the project type is? What should happen if 2 or more projects are selected in the slicer (that have different project types)? Sample data & a picture of how you want the end result to work would be very helpful.

Comment: This question can be answered only if i can have sample data what you are dealing with..

Answer (score 0):

You can show both the charge ratio & bill utilization in a single visual.

**Simple Solution**

A simple solution would be to remove Project from your chart legend and instead have 2 measures on your chart: one for Charge Ratio and one for Bill Utilization. Since only one measure ever applies to any given project, the chart will only ever show one line for any given project. However, you'd need to use the legend to identify what measure is being shown. Further, you'd need to ensure only one project is ever selected at a time: otherwise, it will aggregate the ratios of different projects together.

**Alternative Solution**

Since the Charge Ratio only applies to FP projects, and Bill Utilization only applies to T&M projects, you can create a single calculated column that identifies the type of project and shows either the Charge Ratio or the Bill Utilization as appropriate. E.g.

```
Ratio =
IF (
  RELATED ( 'Project'[Project Type] ) = "FP",
  [Charge Ratio],
  [Bill Utilization]
)
```

You could use the same logic to create a "title" column too:

```
Ratio Name =
IF (
    RELATED ( 'Project'[Project Type] ) = "FP",
    "Charge Ratio By Month (FP)",
    "Bill Utilization By Month (T&M)"
)
```

Finally, you can have a title measure to handle when multiple projects are selected (possibly of multiple types):

```
Ratio Name Measure =
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( 'Ratios'[Ratio Name] ),
    MAX ( 'Ratios'[Ratio Name] ),
    "Charge Ratio & Bill Utilization By Month"
)
```

---

Throw that measure into a multi-row card just above your chart, and it looks like this:
[image: Line chart and a slicer with 2 projects selected]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend utilizing Bookmarks, a button, and visibility controls to toggle visibility between two different charts.

Go to view and check Bookmarks Pane and Selection Pane.  Add two copies of your chart, two bookmarks, and Home >> Button twice.

All assets are nested on top of each other.  Save one bookmark with a button visible and the other hidden.  One chart visible, and the other hidden.  Save the other the opposite way.  Make sure to name all of your assets so you can keep track of them.  Go to your bookmark and update it.

Click your button and go to Action and turn it on, set both to opposite bookmarks.

Final state will have a button that switches to the other bookmark, and one that flips back to the first. One will turn off the chart for FP and turn on the T&M, and the other will turn off T&M and turn on FP.